# Validation loss decreases fast while training is slow

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Iam training a Unet on CT data containing 64 images for each patient. 
While training I observe that the valiation loss is decreasing really fast, while the training loss decreases very slowly.

After about 20 epochs, the validation loss is quite constant while it takes 500 epochs for the training loss to converge.

I already tried a deeper network as well as other Learning rates, but the model behaves the same.

Thanks for any advice,

Cheers,

M

Comment: Too much dropout? Badly processed data?

Comment: Dropout is quite low (0.1) and it doesn't make any difference if I train without It. One thing I was thinking about was that only the central slices of the stack are very different, while the rest is quite easy to Learn. Depending on how I shuffle the validation set, training works or not. I cannot explain how shuffling the validation set should effect training though.